# Putting tires onto axles

Tags: building

I have vintage Lego sets (1970's and '80's).  I absolutely cannot get the tire to fit completely over the axle.  Should I try grease or hot water?  I know this is the correct tire because I have some that already have the tire over the axle.  Please help!!

[image]

Comment: Does the assembly on the right side picture the issue where left tire fits nicely and the right one doesn't?

Answer (score 2):

From my experience with [tires](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3139&idColor=11#T=P&C=11) you mention is that they don't sit symmetrically when placed improperly as they should be. Try going around the tire and pulling it slightly outwards as well as twisting a little from the side with larger outside diameter to center.

This happens with newer sets also.

Answer (score 0):

The small tires [Tire 14mm D. x 4mm Smooth Small Single](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3139&in=P) , fit the brick on the left side [Brick, Modified 2 x 2 with Wheels Red for Single Tire](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3137c01&in=P)

not the plate on the rightside [Plate, Modified 2 x 2 with Wheels Red](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=122c01&in=P)

you will need different tires for that one

Comment: While none of the sets had the combination in question, both the brick and plate seem to have the same axle: [brick](https://www.bricklink.com/TL/25218.jpg) and [plate](https://www.bricklink.com/PL/122c01.jpg). So they should be compatible.